# DexException: Multiple dex file definition

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex

I am getting an error in Android Studio for my application which is as follows:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForInmemoryDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Dependencies included are :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile ('junit:junit:4.12')
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1')
compile ('com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:0.9.10@aar')
compile ('com.squareup:otto:1.3.6')
compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2')
compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+')
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:+')
}
```

I have tried tried setting multidex to true but it still doesn't solve the problem. I have also tried excluding support-v4 in dependencies.

Please help me resolve the error.

Comment: With multiDexEnabled it gives me this error



`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForInmemoryDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/net/TrafficStatsCompat$TrafficStatsCompatImpl.class`

Answer (score -2):

write this on your `build.gradle` "compile `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` in dependency 
Then Open your application class and inside `attachBaseContext` method 
write `MultiDex.install(this);`
Hope it would help you

Comment: Thank you but this didn't help me.